# Auto-increment ids with multiple inserts in mysql/mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb, auto-increment

Suppose I have a table with an auto_increment column, and then insert multiple values in a single statement:

`insert into foo (bar) values ('a'), ('b'), ('c');`

From the documentation, `last_insert_id()` returns the first generated ID for the query, the ID for `a` in this case.

Does mysql give any guarantees that a `b` and `c` will then be assigned sequential values?

In other words, if last_insert_id() returns 1 for `a`, is there any guarantee that b = 2 and c = 3? Or could there be a scenario where due to multiple concurrent inserts, I could end up with something like "a = 1, b = 5, c = 9"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, for that particular statement, MySQL knows how many rows are going to be inserted, and a lock and/or a mutex is used to retrieve the ids to be inserted at the start of the query. It is fully deterministic and **values will be consecutive**.

However, depending on the variable `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode`, **other non-trivial inserts like** `insert... on duplicate key update` and `insert... select` **may not guarantee that deterministic behavior** (as they may not know the actual number of rows to be inserted). This is to allow for extra concurrency by sacrifying the consecutive values. In all cases, a unique, monotonically increasing value is guaranteed for the table as a whole, it is just that in some cases there may be gaps and interleavings.

You can know more about [innodb autoinc behavior in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-auto-increment-configurable.html). And you can also test it in practice by doing:

```
$ mysql test -e "INSERT INTO test (session) VALUES (1), (sleep(1)), (1)"
```

while you insert as fast as possible other value in concurrency.

**Addendum**: I just realized a case in which you cannot assume that: [if you use auto_increment_offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895679/mysqls-auto-increment-behavior-in-a-multiple-row-insert) :-)